# Why does vertical-align: middle causes other elements to misalign?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

With this code:

```css
.header {
  background-color: #444;
  height: 56px;
  color: white;
}

a {
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  background-color: #444;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://directoryapp.trimian.com/img/directory/ic_search_white.png" />
  </a>
  <input placeholder="Search" />
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/o6Gh6tARL7Kt1zxNHaFO?p=preview

[image: bad alignment]

Why is the image misaligned? If I remove the `vertical-align: middle` on the input the image lines up fine.

[image: good alignment]

In the chrome inspector the bounding box that is highlighed for the image also doesn't correspond to where it is rendered on the page (the bounding box is correct).

Am I designing the CSS for this header bar wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying vertical-align to one element doesn't cause miss-alignment for another element.

If you don't apply the vertical-align then both element (in your example) would be aligned same by the browser. Suppose if browser default is `vertical-align: top;` then both element is aligned to top. So, you see no miss-alignment between them. But when you use `vertical-align: middle` to one and leave default for another then browser default alignment and your alignment mismatch. So, you see miss-alignment between them.

To conclude, use vertical-align on both element so that browser will render accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

here is what I would do:

apply same `line-height` as the `height` and remove the `vertical-align:middle`.

here is a snippet:

```css
.header {
  background-color: #444;
  height: 56px;
  color: white;
}
a {
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 56px;  /*new */
}
input {
  background-color: #444;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 56px;  /*changed from 24 to 56px */
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://directoryapp.trimian.com/img/directory/ic_search_white.png" />
  </a>
  <input placeholder="Search" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `vertical-align: middle;` for the image also..